# React: How do I render a child component multiple times and alter each one's unique props using the parent's state?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am building an app that allows users to input text and alter that text box. I want the user to be able to create multiple text boxes and to alter each one individually. There are two child components. The DraggableText and the EditText. The Edit text provides the users with the controls to alter the DraggableText. Here is my code. Thanks!

```
class DesignStudio extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activetext: false,
      textitem: [
        {
          textid: 0,
          userInput: "",
          fontsizevalue: "24",
          fontColor: "black",
          fontWeight: "",
          fontStyle: "",
          textDecoration: "",
          fontFamily: "Andale Mono, monospace",
          rotatedegrees: "0"
        }
      ],
      showColors: false,
      selectButtonClicked: false,
      rotatedegrees: "0"
    };

    this.textActiveHandler = this.textActiveHandler.bind(this);
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.handleUserInput = this.handleUserInput.bind(this);
    this.bolden = this.bolden.bind(this);
    this.italicize = this.italicize.bind(this);
    this.underline = this.underline.bind(this);
    this.showcolors = this.showcolors.bind(this);
    this.setFontFamily = this.setFontFamily.bind(this);
    this.handlesliderchange = this.handlesliderchange.bind(this);
    this.selectButtonClicked = this.selectButtonClicked.bind(this);
    this.addNewTextBoxHandler = this.addNewTextBoxHandler.bind(this);
  }

  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      textitem: update(this.state.textitem, {
        [this.state.textid]: {
          fontsizevalue: { $set: e.target.value }
        }
      })
    });
  }

  textActiveHandler(e) {
    if (this.state.activetext === false) {
      this.setState({ activetext: true });
    } else {
      this.setState({ activetext: false });
    }
  }

  handleUserInput(e) {
    this.setState({
      textitem: update(this.state.textitem, {
        [this.state.textid]: { userInput: { $set: e.target.value } }
      })
    });
  }

  handleChangeComplete = (color, event) => {
    this.setState({
      textitem: update(this.state.textitem, {
        [this.state.textid]: { fontColor: { $set: color.hex } }
      })
    });
  };

  bolden(e) {
    if (this.state.textitem[this.state.textid].fontWeight === "") {
      this.setState({
        textitem: update(this.state.textitem, {
          [this.state.textid]: { fontWeight: { $set: "bold" } }
        })
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        textitem: update(this.state.textitem, {
          [this.state.textid]: { fontWeight: { $set: "" } }
        })
      });
    }
  }

  italicize(e) {
    if (this.state.textitem[this.state.textid].fontStyle === "") {
      this.setState({
        textitem: update(this.state.textitem, {
          [this.state.textid]: { fontStyle: { $set: "italic" } }
        })
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        textitem: update(this.state.textitem, {
          [this.state.textid]: { fontStyle: { $set: "" } }
        })
      });
    }
  }

  underline(e) {
    if (this.state.textitem[this.state.textid].textDecoration === "") {
      this.setState({
        textitem: update(this.state.textitem, {
          [this.state.textid]: {
            textDecoration: { $set: "underline" }
          }
        })
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        textitem: update(this.state.textitem, {
          [this.state.textid]: { textDecoration: { $set: "" } }
        })
      });
    }
  }

  showcolors(e) {
    if (this.state.showColors === false) {
      this.setState({ showColors: true });
    } else {
      this.setState({ showColors: false });
    }
  }

  setFontFamily(e) {
    this.setState({
      textitem: update(this.state.textitem, {
        [this.state.textid]: { fontFamily: { $set: e.target.value } }
      })
    });
  }

  handlesliderchange(e) {
    this.setState({
      textitem: update(this.state.textitem, {
        [this.state.textid]: {
          fontsizevalue: { $set: e.target.value }
        }
      })
    });
  }

  selectButtonClicked(e) {
    if (this.state.selectButtonClicked === false) {
      this.setState({ selectButtonClicked: true });
    } else {
      this.setState({ selectButtonClicked: false });
    }
  }

  addNewTextBoxHandler(e) {
    this.setState({
      textitem: [
        ...this.state.textitem,
        {
          textid: this.state.textitem.length,
          userInput: "Enter New Text",
          fontsizevalue: "24",
          fontColor: "black",
          fontWeight: "",
          fontStyle: "",
          textDecoration: "",
          fontFamily: "Andale Mono, monospace",
          rotatedegrees: "0"
        }
      ]
    });
  }

  render() {
    const activetext = this.state.activetext;
    const showColors = this.state.showColors;
    const selectButtonClicked = this.state.selectButtonClicked;

    let textSlideOut;
    let draggabletext = [];
    let colorSlider;
    let fontSelector;

    if (showColors === true) {
      colorSlider = (
        <div style={{ marginLeft: "10px" }}>
          <CirclePicker
            colors={this.props.colors}
            circleSize={15}
            onChangeComplete={this.handleChangeComplete}
          />
        </div>
      );
    }

    if (showColors === false) {
      colorSlider = <div />;
    }

    if (selectButtonClicked === true) {
      fontSelector = (
        <SelectFont
          onChange={this.setFontFamily}
          value={this.state.textitem[this.state.textid].fontFamily}
        />
      );
    }

    if (activetext) {
      textSlideOut = (
        <div
          style={{
            width: "400px",
            height: "600px",
            border: "1px solid #574904",
            position: "fixed",
            marginLeft: "-175px",
            marginTop: "244px",
            zIndex: "10",
            backgroundColor: "white",
            borderTopRightRadius: "8px",
            borderBottomRightRadius: "8px",
            borderBottomLeftRadius: "8px",
            overflow: "auto"
          }}
        >
          <div
            style={{
              borderLeft: "none",
              borderBottom: "1px solid #574904",
              borderTop: "1px solid #574904",
              borderTopRightRadius: "8px",
              height: "60px",
              marginLeft: "-44px",
              marginTop: "-1px",
              backgroundColor: "#f2f2f2",
              zIndex: "9"
            }}
          >
            <button onClick={this.addNewTextBoxHandler}>
              Add New Text Box +
            </button>
          </div>

          <EditText
            id={this.state.textid}
            handleUserInput={this.handleUserInput}
            userInput={this.state.textitem[this.state.textid].userInput}
            selectButtonClicked={this.selectButtonClicked}
            fontFamily={this.state.textitem[this.state.textid].fontFamily}
            fontSelector={fontSelector}
            handlesliderchange={this.handlesliderchange}
            fontsizevalue={this.state.textitem[this.state.textid].fontsizevalue}
            bolden={this.bolden}
            italicize={this.italicize}
            underline={this.underline}
            showcolors={this.showcolors}
            colorSlider={colorSlider}
          />
        </div>
      );
    }

    if (this.state.textitem.length > 0) {
      for (i = 0; i < this.state.textitem.length; i++) {
        draggabletext.push(
          <DraggableText
            style={{
              marginTop: "100px",
              marginLeft: "100px",
              left: "300px",
              top: "500px",
              zIndex: "2"
            }}
            key={i}
            id={i}
            textInput={this.state.textitem[this.state.textid].userInput}
            borderColor="#574904"
            borderStyle="none"
            borderWidth="1"
            fontSize={this.state.textitem[this.state.textid].fontsizevalue}
            fontColor={this.state.textitem[this.state.textid].fontColor}
            fontWeight={this.state.textitem[this.state.textid].fontWeight}
            fontStyle={this.state.textitem[this.state.textid].fontStyle}
            textDecoration={
              this.state.textitem[this.state.textid].textDecoration
            }
            fontFamily={this.state.textitem[this.state.textid].fontFamily}
            rotatedegrees={this.rotatedegrees}
          />
        );
      }
    }

    return (
      <div className="outerdiv">
        <div className="sidenav">
          <button
            className={
              this.state.activetext === true ? "buttonleftactive" : "buttonleft"
            }
            onClick={this.textActiveHandler}
          >
            <img
              src={textbutton}
              style={{
                width: "40px",
                height: "40px",
                marginLeft: "0px",
                display: "inline"
              }}
              alt=""
            />
            <p style={{ marginLeft: "5px", display: "inline" }}>Add Text</p>
          </button>
        </div>

        <div>{textSlideOut}</div>

        <div className="canvaseditor">{draggabletext}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```